# Using a for loop with JSON

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop

Should be very simple, but I only get Jimmy cricket output and I'm expecting all the names in li tags. Thanks for any help.

```
<ul id="members"></ul>
<script>
var teammembers = [
{"name":"John Doe", "profile":"/img/profile/user1.jpg", "position":"President", "email":"email@example.com", "phone":"242-abcd"},
{"name":"James Bond", "profile":"/img/profile/user2.jpg", "position":"Vice President", "email":"007@example.com", "phone":"242-0007"},
{"name":"Jimmy Cricket", "profile":"/img/profile/user3.jpg", "position":"Vice Cricket", "email":"cricket@example.com", "phone":"242-wxyz"}
];

for (var i = 0; i < teammembers.length; i++) { 
    document.getElementById("members").innerHTML = "<li>" + teammembers[i].name; + "</li>"
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append to the `innerHTML`, rather than set it. Instead of this:

```
document.getElementById("members").innerHTML = "<li>" + teammembers[i].name; + "</li>"
```

use this (the change is from using `=` to using `+=`):

```
document.getElementById("members").innerHTML += "<li>" + teammembers[i].name; + "</li>"
```

Answer (score 3):

The `=` sign here is replacing the innerHTML on each iteration. Hence you see the last value of the array here.

Convert it to a `+=`. Like this,

```
 document.getElementById("members").innerHTML += "<li>" + teammembers[i].name; + "</li>"
```

`+=` will append it.